# About symmetric conditions and $XX'|_a^b\le0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

If $X$ is an eigenfunction satisfying the boundary conditions and $XX'|_a^b\le0$ , then there is no negative real eigenvalues.

Prove that this is valid for symmetric condition.

**Attempt**

Is symmetric condition if  $f'g-fg'|_a^b=0$.

Then $(f'g-fg')(b)=(f'g-fg')(a).$

From here can I say that $a=b$ ?

If yes, then $ff'|_a^b\le0$ follows immediately.

If not, then what can I do to prove that symmetric condition satisfies $XX'|_a^b\le0$ ?

Comment: Can you clarify what $f$ and $g$ are and what $X$ is an eigenfunction of?

Comment: Hi, I just say your answer on the bounty question, thank you, i'm about to read it

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 $f$ and $g$ are real functions. $X$ is just a representation of any function, so you can put $f$ instead of $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is an eigenfunction, i.e. a nonzero function satisfying $-X''=\lambda X$ for some $\lambda$, subject to a pair of boundary conditions. The boundary conditions are called symmetric if, for any pair of functions $f$ and $g$ which satisfy both boundary conditions, $(f'g-fg')|_a^b = 0$.

Assume $XX'|_a^b\leq 0$ for all eigenfunctions $X$ which satisfy the boundary conditions. By Green's First Identity,

$$\int_a^b X''Xdx = XX'|_a^b-\int_a^bX'^2dx$$

$$\Rightarrow XX'|_a^b = \int_a^b X''X + X'^2dx = \int_a^b -\lambda X^2 + X'^2dx \leq 0 $$

If $\lambda < 0$, then $-\lambda X^2+X'^2 > 0$, so $\int_a^b -\lambda X^2 + X'^2dx > 0$, a contradiction. Thus, $\lambda \geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you Alexander :), just one question, how do you guarantee that $\int_a^b -\lambda X^2 + X'^2dx > 0$ ? What if $a<0$ and $b<0,$ doesn't affect the value of the integral?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is positive between $a$ and $b$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ will be positive as well. Think about about the picture: $f$ is above the $x$-axis, and the integral is the area between $f$ and the axis, which is all above the axis and so it is positive.